# What is the best practice on pagination urls in response of a request

Tags: swift, rest, api

In response of some request which returns number of data with pagination, I faced with two keys those refer to links to next page and previous page of current page.

```
{
    "data": {
        "next": "http://localhost/api/contents/posts/?page=3",
        "count": 132,
        "previous": "http://localhost/api/contents/posts/?page=1",
        "items": []
          }
}
```

In some code developers use these urls to access to next and previous data.

But In my case I am generating url of each request at its method call and append base url in request method. here is my code:

**Constants Class:**

```
struct Urls {
    static let baseUrl = "http://localhost/api"

    // MARK:- Content Api
    struct Post {
          static let baseContentURL = "/contents"

          static let posts = "/posts"
      }
     }
```

**Post Request Generator class:**

```
func postListByPage(_ pageNumber: String, completion: @escaping(_ inner : () throws -> Post) -> Void) {
        let relativeUrl = Urls.Post.baseContentURL + Urls.Post.posts + "/?page=" + pageNumber

// get request code
}
```

**API Call class:**

```
func getRequest(relativeUrl: String, tryCount: Int = 1, completion: @escaping (_ inner: () throws -> Data) -> Void) {
let url = Urls.baseUrl + relativeUrl

//send request by URLSession
}
```

I am not sure what is the exact usage of next url when I able to handle these request dynamically and Also I think using this field breaks all rules of layers in API calls in my code.

***My questions:***

1. What is the exact usage of these fields?
2. If using these fields are better, how can I do that with current
   structure?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the exact usage of these fields?

The API you are using wants you to *not* use query parameters to do paging, and manually extract the page number.

A common reason for this is because they follow an actual RESTful architecture and use links to change state, or maybe they want to keep the door open to changing their paging mechanism without breaking clients.

> If using these fields are better, how can I do that with current structure?

Your code doesn't model or abstract the API you are working with well. It's basically the wrong abstraction for the model how the API wants to work.

So I can't really tell you how to work with the API model without changing yours, because it sounds like: "How can I fix this problem without making changes."

Comment: OK, I am ready to change my structure, could you explain how can I do that? Is any toturial about API model implemetation in clients?

Comment: When I was faced with a strict REST api where every relation (and page) was communicated as a link, I ended up writing a little library for it: https://github.com/evert/ketting

Comment: The 'primitive' really is 'follow'. But I imagine if you're only interested in fixing this for paging, you could create a class that's responsible for getting 'next pages' and maintains a list of pages. Designing that class is a bit out of scope for stack overflow though.

Comment: I am thinking about adding "absoluteURL" as parameter to each method and handle it. Thank you for your answer.